# "date" returning a month as a 3-char word

Tags: linux, terminal, date, utilities

At the moment I call `date` this way:

```
  date '+%Y %m %d' 
  # ==> 2017 12 01
```

How should I adjust it so that it return a month in the 3-char format? Like this:

```
 date '+%Y %m %d'
 # ==> 2017 dec 01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `date '+%Y %b %d' | tr A-Z a-z`

Comment: Or you may use the translate command (`tr`) with character sets like `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`. See `man tr` for more information.